# Counting a specific consecutive character with its occurrence position and length

Tags: fasta, text-processing

I have a sequence file and want to count consecutive character "N", with the tandem's position of occurrence and its length. Say I have a file named `mySequence.fasta` like this:

```
>sequence-1 
ATCGCTAGCATNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCTAGCATCATGCNNNNNNATACGCATCACANNNNNNNNNCgcatATCAC
```

and anticipated output should be like this:

```
Position 12 N 15
Position 38 N 6
Position 56 N 9
```

Kindly help me to solve this by `awk` or `sed` providing my file name `mySequence.fasta`

Comment: Why are you tied to awk and sed?  There are many tools in programming languages like python, perl and java that are designed for this.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't come up with a one liner but have a two liner instead...

To get the start positions of the N repeat:

```
grep N mySeq.fasta | grep -b -o N | awk -F: '{print $1}' |awk '$1!=p+1{print $1}{p=$1}'
12
38
56
```

To get the length of the repeats:

```
grep N mySeq.fasta | awk -F '[^N]+' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i != "") print length($i)}' 
14
6
9
```

With thanks to stack overflow.